# Access properties from a function inside Alpine JS

Tags: javascript, alpine.js

I try to use some of my jQuery plugins within Alpine (of course Alpine should replace jQuery in long-term). This autocomplete plugin theoretically works as expected, but I can't set the targetCustomerId from within the onSelect(). How can I access and change the values of my object properties from inside the autocomplete functions?

```
x-data="
        postForm($el.id, 'contracts/add', {
            targetCustomerId: '<?=$customer->CUSTOMERID;?>',

            init() {
                customerInput = $($refs.autocompleteInput).autocomplete({
                    type: 'POST',
                    serviceUrl: 'api/getCustomers',
                    onSearchStart: function() {
                        $(this).addClass('input-loader')
                    },
                    onSearchComplete: function() {
                        $(this).removeClass('input-loader')
                    },
                    onSearchError: function() {
                        $(this).removeClass('input-loader')
                    },
                    onSelect: function (suggestion) {
                        this.targetCustomerId = suggestion.value;
                    }
                });
            }
        })
    "
```

The postForm() is simplified just something like this:

```
function postForm(formId, url, objSettings) {
    var defaults = {
        form: document.getElementById(formId),
        formData: '',
        message: '',
        isLoading: false
    }

    return {...defaults, ...objSettings};
}
```

Comment: Could you also share the definition of `postForm` function and some form code? Do you try to use `targetCustomerId` as an Alpine.js variable?

Comment: @Dauros the postForm() is unneccessary for this example. it just does some basic form preparation and "return {...defaultsSettings, ...customSettings};", where customSettings is the third parameter of postForm(). I want to use/set targetCustomerId as an Alpine.js variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to https://github.com/devbridge/jQuery-Autocomplete's documentation, inside the `onSelect` method, the `this` variable [refers the input element](https://github.com/devbridge/jQuery-Autocomplete#event-function-settings-local-and-ajax) so we cannot access Alpine.js context like this, we have to use e.g. [`$data` magic](https://alpinejs.dev/magics/data).

Assuming the response data looks like this:

```
{
    "suggestions": [
        { "value": "Customer 1", "data": 1 },
        { "value": "Customer 2", "data": 2 }
    ]
}
```

So the `data` refers to `CustomerId` not the `value` field, the modified `onSelect` method:

```
onSelect: function (suggestion) {
    $data.targetCustomerId = suggestion.data;
}
```

Here `$data` refers to Alpine.js data object, and `suggestion` is the clicked autocomplete item.

Comment: thanks a lot. $data was exactly what I was looking for :)